# jQuery Passing parameters in drop option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a droppable element that accepts two selectors, and on drop function is actually a function that call another appropriate function depending on the object class that was dropped.Here is code

```
function setDroppable()
{
    $(".droppable-tile").droppable({
        accept: '.draggable-task, .tile',       //add draggable event
        tolerance:  'pointer',
        drop: function(event,ui){
            if(ui.draggable.hasClass('draggable-task')){
                dropTask(event,ui);
            }
            else {
                dropTile(event,ui);
            }
        },
        hoverClass: "tile-hover"
    });
}
```

When I try to test this in the browser, following error occurred:

jquery-1.12.4.js:253 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on droppable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'

Comment: wrap your function with `$(document).ready(function(){ .....function is here .... })`

Comment: You mean like this : $(document).ready(function(){
 setDroppable(); It is already working like that

Comment: Upgrade jQuery to at least 2+ but it should be ok using 3+, what version jQueryUI are you using?

Comment: Its  a test area Im using sources: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js || https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js